# Prolog: Define propositional logic statement operators and add arguments to list

Tags: list, prolog, operators

I'm trying to define some operators that add the operators with the arguments and the lone arguments to a list.

So far I've defined the two operators I'm gonna use, which are OR and NEGATION, but i don't know how to specify the actions they have to do next, which are creating the lists and add the operators and arguments to it.

```
:- op(400,fx,neg).
:- op(500,xfx,or).
```

After that I'm not certain of how to add the operators and arguments to a list and make a union of all the lists.
According to the union instruction in the manual it would be something like this:

```
neg(X,[]) :- union([X],[neg(X)],[]).
or(X,Y,[]) :- union([X],[or(X,Y)],[]).
or(X,Y,[]) :- union([Y],[or(X,Y)],[]).
```

Which doesn't send any errors, but how do I make the union of all the lists and how do I specify that any lower case letter can be used for input.

An example of an imput would be:

```
neg(a or b).
```

And the expected output:

```
[neg(a or b), a or b, a, b]
```

Comment: How would the "lone arguments" be added to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into an interesting global thing about Prolog that operators really bring to the surface, which is that operators are just another way of constructing terms.

These operator definitions of yours enable you to create terms, such as:

```
?- X = neg a or b.
X = neg a or b.
```

Endowing these terms with *meaning*, on the other hand, will require you to create another predicate. This is because terms in Prolog are not expressions that reduce on their own—this is partly why you need to use `is/2` to reduce an arithmetic expression to a value. Even things that are purely arithmetic are just terms in Prolog:

```
?- X = 16*3 + 4.
X = 16*3+4.
```

This is not some special behavior of `=/2` in Prolog. This is how terms are made. Reducing the value requires deploying another predicate:

```
?- X is 16*3+4.
X = 52.
```

So what you appear to have done is assumed that your `neg` operator has induced a two-argument predicate for reducing it and that your `or` operator has induced a three argument predicate for reducing it. Actually neither of these things has happened, all that your operator declarations do is allow you to create terms like the one above, `neg a or b`. So you still need to create a separate predicate for evaluating them, which is where your semantics enter the picture. So let's implement an `eval/2` predicate that converts your term into the result value you want:

```
eval(neg X, [neg X|Result])   :- 
    eval(X, Result).

eval(X or Y, [X or Y|Result]) :- 
    eval(X, R1), 
    eval(Y, R2), 
    append(R1, R2, Result).

eval(X, [X]) :- atomic(X).
```

The key idea here is to match what your operators give you and peel one layer off at a time, recursively calling the rest. Our base case is "atomic values" which is to say atoms like `a`.

This gives us what you're looking for:

```
?- eval(neg (a or b), R).
R = [neg (a or b), a or b, a, b]
```

Note that `is/2` is an operator. You could also define an operator which "does work" by declaring the operator and then supplying rules for their application. That won't help you in this case, because your examples for `neg` and `or` require you to retain structure rather than discard it. `is/2`, on the other hand, assumes the structure exists on the right argument and reduces it to a value for the left. You could do something similar, by say making `eval/2` an operator, in which case the operator is used on the left side of the `:-`, like so:

```
[Neg X|R] eval (neg X) :- R eval X.
```

However, I find this kind of hard to handle and would definitely avoid it unless it ushered in more clarity.

By the way, you will most likely want to replace `xfx` in your `op/3` call with either `xfy` or `yfx`, since constructions like `a or b or c` will not work with `xfx` due to an operator priority clash. With `xfy`, it will be parsed as `a or (b or c)` and with `yfx` it will be parsed as `(a or b) or c` which is probably more helpful. And also, if you intend *always* to parenthesize what you use `neg` with, then you do not need to declare an operator for it—the purpose of a unary operator is just to allow you to skip the parens (and control how much of what follows is consumed by it.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Many things just became clear to me, even things I wasn't looking to understand.

Comment: @SebastianM. That is wonderful to hear! I always hope to help like that. Welcome to Prolog!